# How to validate and update the data from a previous page in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-form-builder

I wanted to know as to how can I submit the form which will print the user data from a previous page as well as the current page it is in?  This will help me further when I am trying to update user data on firestore. I couldn't find a solution hence I would really appreciate whatever help I can get! :)

edit:
For anyone who didn't get what I was trying to say

I have the textfields of First Name, Last name and age in one page for which the user will press on the next button when done entering. In the final registration page which consists of email and password textfields contains the Register button which will register the user. I want to press Register on the final registration page which will print the data entered in the previous page as well as the current page. I wanted to know how can I achieve that so that later on I can update the user data to firestore

previous page

```
class UserDetails extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _UserDetailsState createState() => _UserDetailsState();
}

enum Gender{
  Male, Female, Others
}

class _UserDetailsState extends State<UserDetails> {
  String userFirstName;
  String userLastName;
  String user_age;
  int group_value = -1;
  Gender _gender = Gender.Male;
   final formkeyDetails = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //final _userProvider = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context);

    final _firstName = Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
      child: TextFormField(
        autofocus: false,
        keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
        /*onChanged: (value){
          _userProvider.changeFirstName(value);
        },

         */
        validator: (value) {
          if(value.isEmpty)
          {
            return 'Field cannot be empty';
          }
          return null;
        },
        onSaved: (value)=> userFirstName = value,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: 'Enter First Name',
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );

    final _lastName = Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
      child: TextFormField(
        autofocus: false,
        keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
       /* onChanged: (value){
          _userProvider.changeLastName(value);
        }
        ,
        */
        validator: (value) {
          if(value.isEmpty)
          {
            return 'Field cannot be empty';
          }
          return null;
        },

        onSaved: (value)=> userLastName = value,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: 'Enter Last Name',
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );





    final _userAge = Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
      child: TextFormField(
        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
        autofocus: false,
       /* onChanged: (value){
          _userProvider.changeAge(value);
        },

        */
        validator: (value) {
          if(value.isEmpty)
          {
            return 'Field cannot be empty';
          }
          return null;
        },
        onSaved: (value)=> user_age = value,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: 'Enter Age',
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );




    final _male = Radio(
      value: Gender.Male,
      activeColor: Colors.black,
      groupValue: _gender,
      onChanged: (Gender value){
        setState(() {
          print(value);
          _gender = value;
        });
      },
    );


    final _female = Radio(
      activeColor: Colors.black,
    value: Gender.Female,
    groupValue: _gender,
    onChanged: (Gender value){
      setState(() {
        print(value);
        _gender = value;
      });
    },
    );

    final _others = Radio(
      activeColor: Colors.black,
        value: Gender.Others,
        groupValue: _gender,
        onChanged: (Gender value){
          setState(() {
            print(value);
            _gender = value;
          });
        },
      );


    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
      body: Container(
        child: Form(
          key: formkeyDetails,
          child:  Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text("Register",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 64.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
              SizedBox(height: 50,),
              _firstName,
              SizedBox(height: 20,),
              _lastName,
              SizedBox(height: 20,),
              _userAge,
              SizedBox(height: 30,),
              Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center ,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text("      Gender: ", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),),
                  _male,
                  Text("Male"),
                  _female,
                  Text("Female"),
                  _others,
                  Text("Others"),
                ],
              ),

              Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center ,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,

                children: <Widget>[
                  FloatingActionButton.extended(
                      heroTag: "prev_button",
                      backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
                      foregroundColor: Colors.black,
                      onPressed: ()=> Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>UserLogin())),
                      label: Text("Prev", style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),)
                  ),
                  FloatingActionButton.extended(
                      heroTag: "next_button",
                      backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
                      foregroundColor: Colors.black,
                      onPressed: ()=> Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>UserReg())),
                      label: Text("Next", style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),)
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        ),
      );

  }
}
```

Current page (which will print the contents of the previous page as well)

```
class UserReg extends StatefulWidget {
  UserReg({this.auth});
  final BaseAuth auth;
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _UserRegState();
}

  class _UserRegState extends State<UserReg> {


    final formkey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  static String emailValidator(String value) {
    Pattern pattern =
        r'^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$';
    RegExp regex = new RegExp(pattern);
    if (!regex.hasMatch(value)) {
      return 'Email format is invalid';
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  static String pwdValidator(String value) {
    if (value.length <= 6) {
      return 'Password must be longer than 8 characters';
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  bool _validateAndSave()
  {
    final form2 = formkey.currentState;
    final form1 = formkeyDetails.currentState;
    if(form2.validate())
      {
        form.save();
        return true;
      }
    return false;
  }

  void _validateAndSubmit() async
  {

      if(_validateAndSave()) {
        try {
          String userId = await Auth().signUp(rEmail, rPass);
          await Auth().sendEmailVerification();
          formkey.currentState.reset();
          print('Registered! $userId, sent email verification');
        }
        catch (e) {
          print('Error: $e');
        }
      }

  }

  final notValidIcon = Icon(
    Icons.error,
    color: Colors.pink,
  );

  static String rEmail;
  static String rPass;





  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //final userProvider = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context);

    final _regEmail = Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
      child: TextFormField(
        keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
        autofocus: false,
        validator: (value) {
          if(value.isEmpty)
          {
            return 'Email cannot be empty';
          }
          else
            emailValidator(value);
          return null;
        },
        /*onChanged: (value){
          userProvider.changeEmail(value);
        },

         */
        onSaved: (value)=> rEmail = value,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: 'Enter Email Address',
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );


    final _regpass = Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
      child: TextFormField(
        obscureText: true,
        autofocus: false,
        validator: pwdValidator,
        /*onChanged: (value){
          userProvider.changePassword(value);
        },

         */
        onSaved: (value)=> rPass = value,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: 'Enter password',
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );

    final _confPass = Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
      child: TextFormField(
        obscureText: true,
        autofocus: false,
        validator: (value){
          if(value != rPass)
            {
              return("Password does not match");
            }
          return pwdValidator(value);
        },
        /*
        onChanged: (value){
          userProvider.changePassword(value);
        },

         */
        onSaved: (value)=> rPass = value,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: 'Enter password',
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );

    return new Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
      backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
      body: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        child: Form(
          key: formkey,
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment:  CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *0.2,),
              Text('Register',
                style:TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 64,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 100,),
              _regEmail,
              SizedBox(height: 20,),
              _regpass,
              SizedBox(height:30),
              //_confRegPass,
              SizedBox(height: 30,),
              FloatingActionButton.extended(
                  heroTag: "Register_Button",
                  backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
                  foregroundColor: Colors.black,
                  onPressed:  (){
                    _validateAndSubmit();
                   //userProvider.saveUser();
                    Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>UserLogin()));
                  },
                  label: Text("Register", style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),)
              ),

              SizedBox(height: 20,),
              FlatButton(
                child: Text('Already Registered? Sign in!'),
                onPressed: ()=> Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>UserLogin())) ,
              ),
              Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  FloatingActionButton.extended(
                      heroTag: "prev_button1",
                      backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
                      foregroundColor: Colors.black,
                      onPressed:  ()=>  Navigator.pop(context),  //Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>UserDetails())),
                      label: Text("Prev", style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),)
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello Rohit What you want to do please elaborate your issue.

Comment: Hey Sumit, I have the textfields of First Name, Last name and age in one page for which the user will press on the next button when done entering. In the final registration page which consists of email and password textfields contains the Register button which will register the user. I want to press Register on the final registration page which will print the data entered in the previous page as well as the current page. I wanted to know how can I achieve that so that later on I can update the user data to firestore

Comment: Ok, So for my understanding you want to get all previous pages data to on final pages. am I right?.

Comment: Exactly! I know I could pass previous values from one screen to the next screen and carryover both data to the final screen but I wanted a better method to do so

Answer (score 1):

Instead of directly going to the next page, you can validate the form in the current page itself using

```
onPressed: () {
    // Validate returns true if the form is valid, otherwise false.
    if (formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      //Navigation Logic
    }
  }
```

And if you want the data from the previous page then you can refer to https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/passing-data

Comment: Hi! thank you so much for the answer but I want to make sure that all the data (from previous page and final page) goes together and not partially as the user could potentially want to change the data they have provided while registering. And doing what you've told will not let them do it.